# Is there any Cypher Query for to return all the properties of a node but excluding a particular property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Retrieving all the properties of a particular node in `Neo4j` is a used to one among many queries. But How can I retrieve the properties of a node excluding a particular property, the labels, and the ID ?

If this below query is executed by java program after successful connection:

```
MATCH (n: `Group_A`: `Topper`) RETURN n
```

Now, Then the output it prints in screen is:

```
{"id":4, "labels":["Group_A", "Topper"], "name":"tom", "shift":"morning", "salary":"5000", "blood_group":"AB", "specialisation":"C#"}
```

I am expecting all the property of the node (n: `Group_A`: `Topper`), excluding the  property type and its value, the id and the labels associated with the node. 
Hence, the desired output in screen will look like:

```
{"name":"tom", "shift":"morning", "blood_group":"AB", "specialisation":"C#"}
```

========================================================================
[N.B. - I am working with Neo4j jar file where I am firing query of `Neo4j` and getting the result using `println()` method. I have my `Neo4j` running in the background. All are working fine with the successful connection of `Neo4j` but I am insearch of the `Neo4j` query.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

To avoid getting node metadata (in your client results), you should not return a node directly. Instead, you can use the [PROPERTIES()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/scalar/#functions-properties) function to get just the properties in a map:

```
MATCH (n: `Group_A`: `Topper`)
RETURN PROPERTIES(n) AS props
```

But if you *also* want to avoid returning some of the properties (e.g. "salary") as well, you can use the [apoc.map.removeKey()](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.map/apoc.map.removeKey/) function to remove them. Since that function returns a map instead of a node, it will also not contain any metadata (so you would not need to use the `PROPERTIES()` function in this case). For example:

```
MATCH (n: `Group_A`: `Topper`)
RETURN apoc.map.removeKey(n, 'salary') AS props
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I run the code you gave but I have another condition also to exclude a particular property from getting displayed along with the list of all properties, which is still there in the output that is being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use map projection.

All node properties (no metadata)

```
MATCH (n: `Group_A`: `Topper`)
RETURN n {.*}
```

Specific properties

```
MATCH (n: `Group_A`: `Topper`)
RETURN n {.prop1, .prop2}
```